# How can I parse String containing XML tags , so that I can get value of all the sub tags

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing

I have to parse a String containing XML tags like the one hard coded below so that I can get values of all the tags separately. Here when I am using

```
NodeList node = doc.getElementsByTagName("event");
```

It is returning value as "ajain1AnkitJain24-04-199223:09.08"

I want to retrieve value for each tag and store it separately in different variables.

Like for eg in this scenario I want to Store Value as :

```
String UID = ajain1
String FirstName = Ankit
String LastName = Jain
Date date = "24-04-1992 23:09.08"
```

Here is the Sample code I am working on.

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String xmldata = "<event><class></class><data><UID><![CDATA[ajain1]]></UID><FIRSTNAME><![CDATA[Ankit]]></FIRSTNAME><LASTNAME><![CDATA[Jain]]></LASTNAME><DATE><![CDATA[24-04-1992]]></DATE><TIME><![CDATA[23:09.08]]></TIME></data></event>";

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmldata));
            try {
                Document doc = db.parse(is);
                //String message = doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
                //System.out.println(message);

                NodeList node = doc.getElementsByTagName("event");

            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // handle SAXException
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle IOException
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            // handle ParserConfigurationException
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Thanks and let me know if you require any more information.

Comment: Nope, can you guide me to a link or something ?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/index.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll check it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

A `NodeList` already is a list containing all requested nodes, but I have to admit, I find its implementation highly questionable. It's basically a node containing the requested nodes as children. Its implementation has very much nothing in common with other list implementations - it doesn't even implement the List interface. I don't exactly know how to handle `[!CDATA]`, but to loop through all `event` tags you'd have to do something like this:

```
NodeList eventList = doc.getElementsByTagName("event");
for(int i = 0; i < eventList.getLength(); i++) {
  Element eventElement = (Element) eventList.item(i);
  // do some stuff with it
}
```

From this element, you can also use `getElementsByTagName` to get the information needed about first name and so on. And yes, it's likely to end up with many nested loops...